# Problemas con serie numérica en Java

Tags: java

Como parte de un proyecto tengo que desarrollar un programa que imprima los N primeros dígitos de la siguiente serie:

2, -3, -5, -7, 4, 6, -9, -11, -13, 8, 10, 12...

El problema que tengo es que, al ingresar el numero de elementos a mostrar, por ejemplo 3, tendría que imprimirse:

2, -3, -5

Pero se imprime lo siguiente:

2, -3, -5, -7, 4, 6, -9, -11, -13, 8, 10, 12, -15, -17, -19

Les adjunto el código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class tarea12_Serie3{//Inicio class
    public static void main(String[] args) {//Inicio main
        int a=0, b=1, n, i, j,z, aux=0;
        String entrada;
        String letrero="Serie: ";
        ///////////////SE SOLICITA NUMERO DE ELEMENTOS//////////////////////////
        entrada=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar numero de elementos: ");
        n=Integer.parseInt(entrada);
        do{//Inicio do
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {//Inicio for i
                aux=i;
                for(z=1;z<=aux;z++) {//Inicio For z
                    a+=2;
                    letrero=letrero+a+", ";
                }//Fin for z
                for (j=0; j<3; j++) {//Inicio for j
                    b+=2;
                    letrero=letrero+"-"+b+", ";
                }//Fin for j
            }//Fin for i
        }//Fin do
        while(i<=aux);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letrero);
    }//Fin main
}//Fin class
```

Espero alguien me pueda dar alguna idea de lo que pueda estar faltando.

Comment: Tu pregunte esta bien, pero te pediria que expliques que trata de hacer cada parte de tu algoritmo, porque no entiendo la logica. Explicanos la logica de esa serie para que podamos entender la logica de tu programa. por ejemplo i va a ser siempre, pero siempre = a aux, porque en tu for en cada vuelta le das ese valor.

Comment: si ingresa el 3 , entonces tienes que recorrer desde 0 a 2, eso lo puedes hacer en el for y mas nada!